# Convert WebSphere to Liferay project

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, websphere-portal

Currently, I'm migrating my WebSphere project to a Liferay project in Eclipse. I have IBM portlets and JSR 168 portlets. I'm using Eclipse Kepler with Liferay IDE 2.2, but there is no option to "Convert to Liferay project."

What's the best way to change my WebSphere project? I'm newbie at this point and any information about this problem it will be a great help.

Comment: Hi Elsa, take a look at this Liferay forum post: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/7480307

Comment: Ben Vonderhaar, I already knew this post. This post has already 3 years, in which talks about earlier versions of Liferay IDE (actually is 2.2 and portal version 6.2). Actually, there is no other way to do this migration without portlets rebuilding? 
This post also refers - “you can make semi automatic if you are familiar with IWWCM Java API and Liferay Web Content API (Journal in code)” but for me is too unspecific.  Do you know any link or a vídeo tutorial with more exemples for my situation? I can´t find anything…

Comment: Elsa, my point is that there's no magic bullet that will do this conversion for you.  As the feature stack of both technologies change regularly, any kind of porting mechanism would require such a tremendous amount of upkeep that it would be much more trouble than it's worth.  Olaf's first answer in the linked thread is the best course of action for you, as the conversion is highly dependent on what your code does right now.

Answer (score 0):

I developed portlets with Liferay Portal and IBM Portal, and migration between the two does not exist because both portals depend on their internal APIs.
The simplest is to create new portlets in Liferay and go migrating layer by layer :

- Data Access Layer.
- Business Layer .
- View Layer.

I recommend you use **Spring MVC** portlet to develop your portlets because that way your migration to another portal will be a little easier.

> Liferay 6.2.x use Spring 3.0.7